# ios9.1 gets UILocalNotification called twice in one post

Tags: uilocalnotification, ios9.1

`UILocalNotificaiton` gets called twice in one post.

Does anybody know the reason?

I found it in iOS9.1. But in iOS8.0 it works normally.

Below is my code:

```
extension UILocalNotification {
    class func postNotification(message : String!, soundName : String?) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            let localNotification : UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(1)
            localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
            localNotification.alertBody = message
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: 0)

            if soundName != nil {
                localNotification.soundName = soundName
            } else {
                localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            }

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about code you implement in code? You put this question like this? How can people help you :)

Comment: @vienvu Sorry, I edit it again.